# Why the focus is not changing from current textinput to succeding textinput, when we try to change a state before chaging the focus?

Tags: react-native, user-interface, react-hooks, focus, one-time-password

I am trying to create a Enter-otp screen by using react-native.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

import {
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';

import { Grid, Col, Row } from 'react-native-easy-grid';


export default function App() {
  return (
    <OtpValidate/>
  );
}

function OtpValidate() {
  
  const [otp, setOtp] = useState([]);
  const [resendButtonDisableTime, setResendButtonDisableTime] = useState(6);
  const textInputRef = [useRef(), useRef(), useRef(), useRef()];

  useEffect(() => {
    timer();
  }, [resendButtonDisableTime]);

  function timer() {
    const timerObject = setTimeout(() => {
      if (resendButtonDisableTime < 0) clearTimeout(timerObject);
      else setResendButtonDisableTime(resendButtonDisableTime - 1);
    }, 1000);
  }

  const OtpInput = () => {
    const renderOtpInput = ['textInput1', 'textInput2', 'textInput3', 'textInput4'].map(
      (val, index) => (
        <Col>
          <TextInput
            key={index}
            ref={textInputRef[index]}
            style={styles.OtpInput}
            maxLength={1}
            keyboardType="numeric"
            value={otp[index]}
            autoFocus={index === 0 ? true : undefined}
            onChangeText={(value) => changeFocus(value, index)}
          />
        </Col>
      )
    );

    return renderOtpInput;
  };

  function changeFocus(value, index) {
    if (value.length == 1) {
      const otpCopy = otp.concat();
      otpCopy[index] = value;
      setOtp(otpCopy);
      textInputRef[++index].current.focus();
    } else {
      const otpCopy = [...otp];
      otpCopy[index] = null;
      setOtp(otpCopy);
      textInputRef[--index].current.focus();
    }
  }

  return (
    <Grid>
      <Row size={20} style={{ alignItems: 'center', paddingLeft: 10 }}>
        <Text>{'Enter the otp recieved in the device'}</Text>
      </Row>
      <Row size={30}>
        <OtpInput />
      </Row>
      <Row size={10} style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}>
        <View>
          {resendButtonDisableTime > 0 ? (
            <Text>{'Resend otp in ' + resendButtonDisableTime + ' sec'}</Text>
          ) : (
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <Text>{'Resend'}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        </View>
      </Row>
      <Row size={40} style={{ marginHorizontal: 10 }}>
        <Col>
          <Button title="submit" />
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Grid>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  OtpInput: {
    margin: 10,
    padding: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
});
```

In the above code, there is changefocus() function that changes the focus of the textinput when the value entered into textinput is of length one and also saves the value entered into the textinput to a state variable (i.e, otp) by using react hooks.
The problem here is, the textinput focus changes sequentially when we are not changing the state variable(i.e otp). But when we try to change the state-variable first and then change the focus, it does not render. I don't know what is the problem can you please solve it.